# How to change hosting model to InProcess in asp.net core?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I created a new asp.net core MVC project and when I ran it I realised that it is running in OutOfProcess hosting model but I want it to run in InProcess hosting model.

I tried editing csproj file and adding `<AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>` but that didn't work out.

Also, there is no option to select hosting model in my debug properties.

[image: debug properties]

Edit: I am using .net core 2.1

Comment: What version of ASP.NET Core are you targeting? Since there are so many variables involved, I'd suggest to first check these two links: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-2-2-0-preview2-now-available/?WT.mc_id=-blog-scottha and https://appdevmusings.com/host-your-asp-net-core-2-2-web-app-with-iis-in-process-and-out-of-process-hosting-model-and-deploy-to-docker-windows-containers

Comment: Check the **IIS Express Bitness** Drop-down. Here is `InProcess` hosting model option too.

Comment: @TanvirArjel the options here are x64 and x84. Tried setting to x64 still it runs on dotnet.exe (OutOfProcess) model

Comment: @jpgrassi I am using .net core 2.1

Comment: Well, that's it then :) It's only shipped on 2.2. See here: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/3794, also here: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/3265#issuecomment-400454532

Comment: Ok thanks there.. So is there any way I can work it out on 2.1 or I'll have to forcefully upgrade to 2.2?

Comment: @testsys123 You need to upgrade to .net core 2.2